# Identify Raid Failed Drive "serial number" and "Mount name" export to txt

Tags: linux, shell-script, shell, php, raid

I want to write bash script or php file to export output file status.txt of failed raid (hard disk serial no) and (mount name)  or "OK"   I tried some code below far from finish

desired 2 output

```
 status.txt  if In case everything is fine.
    
    a=OK b=OK c=OK
    

    status.txt  In case sn=DH26fd5302 failed.
    
    a=FAIL b=DH26fd5302 c=/dev/md3
```

mdam output

```
[root@gtw4-de ~]# mdadm -vDs /dev/md3 | awk -F= '/^[ ]+devices/ {print $2}' | tr , '\n'
/dev/sda3
/dev/sdb3
/dev/sdc3
/dev/sdd3
[root@gtw4-de ~]# mdadm --detail --scan /dev/md3
ARRAY /dev/md3 metadata=0.90 UUID=f1c7d2cb:a4335wb:a4d2adc2:26fd5302
[root@gtw4-de ~]#
```

mdstat proc

```
[root@gtw4-de ~]# cat /proc/mdstat
Personalities : [raid1] [raid10]

    md6 : active raid10 sda6[0] sdd6[3] sdc6[2] sdb6[1]
          7237440512 blocks 512K chunks 2 near-copies [4/4] [UUUU]
          bitmap: 2/54 pages [8KB], 65536KB chunk
    
    md5 : active raid10 sda5[0] sdc5[2] sdd5[3] sdb5[1]
          153594880 blocks 512K chunks 2 near-copies [4/4] [UUUU]
    
    md2 : active raid1 sdd2[3] sdc2[2] sdb2[1] sda2[0]
          523200 blocks [4/4] [UUUU]
    
    md3 : active raid1 sda3[0] sdc3[2] sdd3[3] sdb3[1]
          209918912 blocks [4/4] [UU_UU]
          bitmap: 2/2 pages [8KB], 65536KB chunk
```

this script only searches _ between [] and gives output OK or FAIL but I want more if its fail I want UUID of fail drive and mount name.

```
#!/bin/sh
if grep -q '\[[^]]*_.*]' /proc/mdstat
then
       (find problem drive which contain _ between [] get mount name then search UUID)
else
        echo "a=OK b=OK c=OK"
fi
```

Comment: Does your script work? If not, what happens? What is it you actually want help with - there's no question in your question

Comment: Does your script work? It doesn't work, because  (find problem drive which contain _ between [] get mount name then search UUID) section is not in place hence I wanted help from others. Or if you have some other ideas from scratch to achieve my goal.which is exporting raid fail or OK echo's

Comment: Please put that information _into your question_.

Comment: Ah. You want to monitor the RAID? Say that _in your question_, as there's then no need for your script at all.

Comment: this is script export information to txt which eventually inserted to database where 100 server raids monitor by us why do you think there is no need ?

Comment: Put this detail and your question into the question text, where it can be easily seen by everyone. Make it easy for people to help you.

Answer (score 0):

It's unclear from your question what you actually want. The comments seem to suggest you want to monitor your RAID arrays, and you're writing a script to do that. On this basis, `mdadm` will already do it for you.

```
mdadm --monitor --scan
```

Make sure you have a correct email address value in `/etc/mdadm/mdadm.conf` for the `MAILADDR` keyword (mine is `root`, which in turn forwards on to the organisation-wide monitoring tool).

There are other options available to `mdadm`. For example, the `PROGRAM` keyword, which,

> gives the name of a program to be run when `mdadm  --monitor` detects potentially interesting events on any of the arrays that it is monitoring. This program gets run with two or three arguments, they being the Event, the md device, and possibly the related component device.

Comment: Perhaps you miss understood whole concept. I wanted to export information that has been provided mdadm and then export this information to file called status.txt. whole idea is to export information to txt not physically run this command for each server

Comment: WHY NOT PUT THAT INTO YOUR QUESTION? (Third time of asking.)

Comment: IT IS CLEARLY WRITTEN THIS IN THE TITLE

Comment: The title isn't the question

Comment: well that's your opinion we'll see.